# Using different lengthed masks gridmaskedcolumn

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

How would I have an input of a variable length in the gridmaskedcolumn. 
For this instance the grid is a password which must have at least 4 characters but can be longer than 4 characters and those characters must be numbers only. Also the characters must not be displayed.

```
<telerik:GridMaskedColumn DataField="Pin" UniqueName="Pin" HeaderText="Pin" Visible="false" Mask="<0..9>" DisplayMask="******" >
            </telerik:GridMaskedColumn>
```

I tried reading for solutions online but it seems there are no solutions regarding a variable lengthen input.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have been reading, GridMaskedColumn is not designed for variable-length input and therefore passwords are not ideal for GridMaskedColumns.

An alternative would be to use a normal GridBoundColumn and set the column mode to password.

```
if (e.Item is GridDataItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
{
    GridDataItem edititem = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
    TextBox txtpwd = (TextBox)edititem["Pin"].Controls[0];
    txtpwd.TextMode = TextBoxMode.Password;
    txtpwd.Visible = true;
}
```